# PN Junction Formation

Tags: diodes, junction

When a PN junction is formed, free electrons from the N type diffuse into the P type material.
Now books say that the same applies for holes, which diffuse from the P type material to the N type one. However, everyone knows hole movement really is a reaction movement of adjacent valence elctrons wanting to hope in the holes(incomplete covalent bonds of Silicon/Germanium for example). Does this mean, that the hole diffusion from P to N realy is a diffusion of valence electrons from N to P, in addition to the diffusion of **free** electrons from N to P?. Am I understanding this correctly? if yes, that means that after the depletion region is formed, we cannot tell *which* electrons in the P type material originate from valence bonds from the N type material and which electrons are free/excess electrons from the N material.

Comment: quantum theory posits you cannot tell one electron from another any way; some theorists argue "all electrons are one" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-electron_universe). This physics.SE question bears on your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/557164/if-electrons-are-identical-and-indistinguishable-how-can-we-say-current-is-the. In short, you can reveal the current of concentrations and the corresponding mechanism (drift, diffusion) and the concentration origins (zones, regions), but not "which electrons in the P type material originate from" bonds, medium etc.

Comment: hi, thanks, but does the hole diffusion from P to N mean that statistically, SOME valence electrons from N _hop_ inside the holes in the P material? for electrons that originate from the N material which are the 5th electrons of donors and diffuse to the P material it is easy to understand, i am just trying to understand if valence electrons indeed contribute to the formation of the junction, since in the end hoping electrons from hole to hole is not the same as electrons moving in the conductions band.

Comment: let us, for a moment, forget about a "hole" concept (although this forgetfulness is not productive) and talk about electrons (free, bound, valence, etc). In equilibrium, you cannot tell what is the origin of electrons in the P material, right? I mean, are they "intrinsic" (P's "native citizens") or "migrants"? Then, you believe that one can watch the process of "formation" of the junction and see individual electrons hopping from an atomic orbitals in N to an atomic orbital in P (so that corresponding holes hop from P to N)?

Comment: Now, won't bore you with the alternative mechanisms of electron/hole migration, like the overlap of thermal distributions, phonon exitation, etc, just remind you that the attempt to trace the movement of individual particles is a classical, non-quantum, approach, and yes, there is no classical explanation for transition of electrons from deep orbitals across potential barriers between individual atoms. More than that, there is no classical explanation even for the existence of atoms.

Comment: So you have no choice other than study solid state physics and think in terms of the concepts of work function, Fermi energy, Fermi level, etc. Not only think, but also measure, calculate and design with full acceptance of solid state physics, and quantum theory in general.

In short, the answer to your question is "adapt yourself to the hole concept and thing in terms of wavefunctions, chemical potential, Fermi level, band bending etc.